# Реализация паттерна "наблюдатель" (подписчик-издатель, observer)

Tags: c++, qt, шаблоны-проектирования

Правильно ли я реализовал этот паттерн?
В данном примере документ может закрыть все открытые документы кроме себя. Для этого за каждым документом для начала закрепляется Application.  Далее, при надобности документ посылает сигнал Application'у о просьбе закрыть все документы кроме себя.

Требование - реализация должна быть основана на событийной модели взаимодействия.

```
class Application //типа наблюдатель (за документами)
{
    std::vector<Document *> docs;
    public:
        void add_document(Document *doc)
        {
            docs.push_back(doc);
        }
    public slots:
        void close_non_active_docs_button_pressed(Document *active_doc)
        {
            для всех idoc кроме doc в this->docs
            idoc->close();
        }
}


class Document
{
    Application *app;

    public:
        void attach_to_app(Application *app)
        {
                this->curr_app = app;
                app->add_document(this);
        }

        void close(){...};

    public signals:
        void close_non_active_docs_button_pressed(Document *active_doc);


    ////////
    ////////
    ....
        emit close_non_active_docs_button_pressed(this);
}

///где то еще есть CONNECT(сигнал и слот)
```

Comment: А точно подписчик-издатель и observer это одно и то же? На wiki это разные паттерны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имеется сущность документа (класс Document), в которой могут происходить изменения связанные со шрифтом, текстом, размерами и т.д., и т.п, и пр. пр. пр.

Данная сущность имеет стойкое желание сигнализировать об этих изменениях во вне различным слушателям. Но она (наша сущность) ничего не хочет знать лишнего о том, с кем она общается. Наш документ хочет лишь, чтобы его слышали при помощи специального протокола (читай интерфейса). Да, этот шаблон порождает эгоистов!

Допустим вот такого (это протокол общения со слушателями):

```
class AbstractDocumentChangedListener {
public:
    virtual void fontSizeChanged(int was, int current) =0;
    virtual void fontNameChanged(string was, string current) =0;
    virtual void textChanged(string was, string current) =0;
}
```

Имея такой протокол мы можем зарегистрировать слушателя в списке слушателей внутри объекта нашего документа:

```
class Document {
public:
    //...
    void addListener(AbstractDocumentChangedListener* listener) {
        _listeners.insert(listener);
    }
    //...
private:
    set<AbstractDocumentChangedListener*> _listeners;
}
```

Теперь каждый, кто хочет узнать, что же там такого происходит с нашим документом, должен реализовать соответствующий интерфейс:

```
class DocumentListener : public AbstractDocumentChangedListener {
public:
    void fontSizeChanged(int was, int current) override {
        //Теперь я знаю, что "они" изменили размер шрифта
    }
    void fontNameChanged(string was, string current) override {
        //Теперь я знаю, что "они" выбрали другой шрифт
    }
    void textChanged(string was, string current) override {
       // Другой текст? Хм, странно )
    }
}
```

А если мне нужны не все методы данного протокола?

```
class SomeDocumentChangedListener : public AbstractDocumentChangedListener {
public:
    void fontSizeChanged(int was, int current) {};
    void fontNameChanged(string was, string current) {};
    void textChanged(string was, string current) {};
}
```

И тогда:

```
class DocumentListener : public SomeDocumentChangedListener {
public:
    void textChanged(string was, string current) { //... }
}
```

В любом случае регистрация слушателя в целевом объекте будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
   //...
   Document doc;
   DocumentListener listener;

   doc.addListener(&listener);
   //...
```

Таким способом этот шаблон реализован и очень широко и часто используется в Java.
Также его можно применять в чистом C++.

В Qt данный принцип реализован через систему signals/slots. Сущности сигнализируют о своих внутренних изменениях при помощи emit , а, соответственно, слушатели получают эти изменения при помощи реализации слотов (slots) при, соответственно, установлении коннекта между ними (connect).

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, классу Document совсем не нужно хранить какие-либо сведения о наблюдателе, в таком случае появляются новые зависимости, что совсем не хорошо. кроме того, было бы хорошо унаследовать Document от общего абстрактного класса, в котором прописать различные сигналы для наблюдателя (в том числе сигнал, информирующий об удалении объекта, чтобы не хранить некорректные ссылки у наблюдателя).

Самого наблюдателя тоже сделать либо шаблонным (тут будет проблема, если унаследован от QObject), либо хранить в списке ссылки на общий класс (интерфейс) наблюдаемых объектов.